# Merging two dataframes on the intersection of a given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge the following two dataframes on their intersection on column 'Name'.

suppose dataframe 1 is:

```
     Name subject_id  Marks_scored
0   Billy       sub1            98
1     Amy       sub2            90
2    Bran       sub4            87
3   Alice       sub6            69
4  Ayoung       sub5            78
```

and dataframe 2 is:

```
    Name subject_id  Marks_scored
0  Billy       sub2            89
1  Brian       sub4            80
2   Bran       sub3            79
3  Bryce       sub6            97
4  Betty       sub5            88
```

I just want the output to be:

```
    Name subject_id  Marks_scored
0  Billy       sub1            98
1   Bran       sub4            87
2  Billy       sub2            89
3   Bran       sub3            79
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `pd.concat` then `duplicated` and boolean indexing:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_out[df_out.duplicated('Name', keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
    Name subject_id  Marks_scored
0  Billy       sub1            98
2   Bran       sub4            87
0  Billy       sub2            89
2   Bran       sub3            79
```

Comment: perhaps `df_out[df_out.Name.isin(set(df1.Name) & set(df2.Name))]` if Names can be duplicated within a given Frame?

Comment: Yes, great this is better than the first because it solves the issue of having duplicate in the 'Name' within the same same dataframe, thanks

Answer (score 5):

`pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')`

OR

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on='subject_id', how='inner')`

Comment: if you want right join how='right' or left join how='left'

Comment: I think neither of these give the desired output